# How to display a textView from onAttach

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

i am checking te fragments lifecycle, and i placed a `textView` inside each callback "onAttache, onViewCreated, ...etc", but the probelm is the `fragment` layout is defined at `onCreateView()` and the later subsequent callbacks and not in `onAttch`. my question is how to display a `text` saying or an example "@onAttach()" from inside the `onAttach()` callback?

Comment: It's great your going with the life cycle but why reinvent?   Fragments should run independent of the activity hence don't worry too much about the onAttach() method.  Same as an activity onResume() a global flag (boolean) if you've not shown your text (false) show the text if you have shown the text (true) then don't update it.

Answer (score 1):

TextView is a UI component and UI becomes ready once onCreateView finishes. Normally you populate your layout XML in onCreateView and then onActivityCreated you get the view elements and manipulate them. ON onAttach callback finishing guarantees that the fragment is attached to the parent activity  but the fragment is not initialized or built up yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can't display `View`s from `onAttach()`. Your first opportunity to inflate and setup UI elements from the fragment is in `onCreateView`.